# Is $S=\{ (3,1,4),(3,4,1),(4,3,1),(3,3,1) \}$ spanning ${\mathbb{R}}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is $S=\{ (3,1,4),(3,4,1),(4,3,1),(3,3,1) \}$ spanning ${\mathbb{R}}^3$ ?

My attempt:
If $S$ spanning ${\mathbb{R}}^3$ then

$(x,y,z)=\alpha_1 (3,1,4)+ \alpha_2(3,4,1)+ \alpha_3(4,3,1)+ \alpha_4(3,3,1) $

$A=\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}} 3 & 3 & 4 & 3 & x\\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 3 & y \\ 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z \end{array}\right]$

when I tried to reduce $A$ to The Echelon form, I got that:

$A=\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}} 1 & 0 & 0 & {{1}\over {24}} & f_1(x,y,z)\\ 0 & 1 & 0 &  {{33}\over {72}} & f_2(x,y,z) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &  {{3}\over {8}} &  f_3(x,y,z) \end{array}\right]$

Now, Is this system has a infinite solutions ? Or no solution ?

“When The non-homogeneous system has a unique solution, infinite solutions, no solution ?”

Comment: Your matrix has rank $3$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has infinite solutions. You can for example choose the parameter $\alpha_4$ arbitrarily in $\mathbb{R}$. Then you get unique values for $\alpha_1=f_1(x,y,z)-\frac{\alpha_4}{24}$, $\alpha_2=f_2(x,y,z)-\frac{33\alpha_4}{72}$ etc.

So, for each vector $(x,y,z)$, you obtain infinitely many combinations in $S$.
This is the case since the first three vectors $b_1,b_2,b_3$ of $S=\{\,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\,\}$ already span $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you ignore the 4th vector, you obtain the echelon form
$$\tilde{A} = \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}1&0&0&\tilde{f_1}(x,y,z)\\0&1&0&\tilde{f_2}(x,y,z)\\0&0&1&\tilde{f_3}(x,y,z)\end{array}\right]$$
giving you unique values for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \alpha_3$ without any choices.
In fact, those three vectors are a *basis* for $\mathbb{R}^3$, since they span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and their cardinality is $3$, which is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Alternatively, you may check that the first three vectors are *linearly independent*, meaning that if $\alpha_1 b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2 + \alpha_3 b_3=0$, you can prove that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0$. Then you obtain that $b_1,b_2,b_3$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so they have to span $\mathbb{R}^3$, too.

Your  third option is to show, that you can generate the three standard basis vectors $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$ with $S$. You probably know that $e_1,e_2,e_3$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$, so $S$ spanns $\mathbb{R}^3$ aswell, if you can generate the standard basis.